# No puede leer por teclado cadenas de char en Linux

Tags: c

Hola en varios programas he intentado leer por consola una cadena de caracteres y el programa salta a la siguiente línea sin pedir la cadena:
He usado estos dos métodos:

```
char cadena[40];
fgets(producto.descripcion,40, stdin); // pertenece a una estructura.
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", cadena);
```

ni fgets ni tampoco scanf cuando se trata de cadenas. Scanf con enteros o floats si va.

Repito en Linux.
uso estas cabeceras:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

¿ Que pude ser ?

Comment: Si es una cadena, ¿por qué no empleas  `%s` dentro del `scanf`? El `%c` es para caracteres mientras que `%s` lo puedes emplear para `string`s.
Y otra cosa, también puedes acceder a la cadena mediante un puntero a la primera posición de la forma `scanf("%s", &cadena[0])`

Comment: No hay nada de malo con ese código. No puedo reproducir el problema que tienes. Mira: https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185My85pzQlVcGmuCQlM18vw44LIZSXXFpUnFqMKghUl5OZBBLjyswrUchNzMzT0KzmUgCC5IzEIoXkxJTUvMRoE4NYa7BgWnpqSbEGRFRHwcRARwFkU54mRLagFC4JFSlOTsxL01BSjY6LyYtV1UpW0lFAkUfVUfv/v0d@TiKXY0rm4c3FXFwA

Comment: Entonces no se si será algo de mi instalación de Linux. He probado scanf("%s" y va genial, incluso sin puntero.